# Typescript ensure a type contain the sub string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I defined a `SizeType` and going to set up the device media query type check. Is it possible that instead of using `string` only on DeviceSize, I can make it have to include the substring `min-width: ...` and then the rest string limit to the value of `size` property?

```
type SizeType = 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl' | 'xxl';
type Size = { [size in SizeType]: string };
type DeviceSize = { [size in SizeType]: string };

interface Theme {
    device: Required<Partial<DeviceSize>>;
}

const size: Size = {
    sm: '576px',
    md: '768px',
    lg: '1024px',
    xl: '1440px',
    xxl: '2560px',
};
const theme: Theme = {
    device: {
        sm: `(min-width: ${size.sm})`,
        md: `(min-width: ${size.md})`,
        lg: `(min-width: ${size.lg})`,
        xl: `(min-width: ${size.xl})`,
        xxl: `(min-width: ${size.xxl})`,
    },
}
```

With the current setting, this will pass the check:

```
const theme: Theme = {
    device: {
        sm: `(min-width: ${size.sm})`,
        md: `(min-width: ${size.md})`,
        lg: `(min-width: 100)`,
        xl: `(min-width: 220px)`,
        xxl: `abc`,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just declare your string type as a template literal with the pattern you want.

```
type DeviceSize = { [size in SizeType]: `(min-width: ${string})` };
```

Which should now give you the error you expect:

```
const theme: Theme = {
    device: {
        sm: `(min-width: ${size.sm})`,
        md: `(min-width: ${size.md})`,
        lg: `(min-width: 100)`,
        xl: `(min-width: 220px)`,
        xxl: `abc`,
        // Type '"abc"' is not assignable to type
        //   '`(min-width: ${string})`'.(2322)
    },
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.4.2&ssl=3&ssc=68&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgLwgFXNAvFA5AZwLZZQA+2eAJoSVgDYDml2AHtQ1o81gNwBQoksiDFADeUANo5BUOADsBSVJAC6ALig5gAJ1m0oAXx59oAEQgA3OAGMI8JFEyiJU2fJRpVUAAYAKPLIC0AO5wZMAAFmoAJMIa2jK0egCUnvo83LLAEJoAZgCG1lDIYRB40MLcUJVQZOZWEGoAShAAjgCucJoQZAA8AAq5msBwudTdphbWthAAfNM8etzclgD2MhrqgmpT9iIVVfhqWACsAOwAbGCMWAA0e5Xkh+cAHJc3d1B0hwCMAAwATAAWV63KpQZjfAEAn7A97saiHP5HM7Qq63AyLFZrYBQcIleqFYqlHblUE1Cb4kmg-Z4NQ+PwyIIhcJRGKCAB0+CSnhBVPuZFpvgCwVCESg0UkSDZ5C5PN5ny8goZwuZUF+P2Ssqp4IV9MZIrUfz+KI171BcNpuQARpZuVAAPR2qBZTTLTRQXI4J2MSCWTJkd56NFAA)

Or even:

```
`(min-width: ${number}px)`
```

If you want to validate that it is some number of `px` units.

Comment: Is it possible limit the size value from size varible on min-width? In your on, (min-width: 100) can still pass.

Comment: You can also validate size units with this helper: `type LengthProperty = `${number}px``